# Retrieve only one item from multivalued field on Solr

Tags: solr

I'm new in Apache Solr and have these data on Solr core:

```
[
  {
    "npu":[29472823],
    "andamentos":["conclusos autos despacho mero expediente",
      "baixa expediente certidao documento restrito",
      "proferido despacho mero expediente",
      "proferido despacho mero expediente",
      "expedido notificacao destinatario"],
    "_version_":1628623714800107520}
]
```

I would like know how do, in Solr Admin, to retrieve only one item from **andamentos field** that attend my query. Example: use the query q='expedido notificacao' and return only the items that contais this query.